# Overloading Operators not working C++

Tags: c++, operators

I have a problem with operator overloading. Bool operators are working ok, but the rest just does not pass right values to specified objects. The thing is that after using `this` operators and displaying area of `Island`, instead of "normal numbers" I get something like `-9.25596e+061`. Area is an attribute from `Island` class. Please help.

Here's declaration of these operators and the rest of the code :

```
Island operator + (const Island &island); // declaration in header file
Island& operator += (const Island &island);

Island Island::operator + (const Island &island) // in .cpp file
{
    Island Sum(); // default constructor which set area to 1
    Sum.area = area + island.area;
    return Sum;
}

Island & Island::operator += (const Island &island)
{
    area += island.area;
    return *this;
}
```

So in the main function i created 3 islands by default constructor and i want to test my operators. 
displayArea() is a method from Island class.

```
Island2 += Island1; // operator +=
Island.displayArea();

Island3 = Island1 + Island2; //operator +
Island3.displayArea();
```

And that's the default constructor and class.

```
Island::Island()
{
    islandName = "Name";
    double area = 1;
}

class Island{
    double area;
    string islandName;

public:
    Island();   //constructor
    displayArea();
```

Comment: A complete code example with the main() function and the expected output could help people to answer.

Comment: May we see your header file?  Are you declaring the operator overload functions inside of your class definition?

Comment: This is not your real code, it never would have compiled.  `Island Sum();` is a function declaration.

Comment: This is not your real code, it wouldn't even compile. `Island Sum();` forward-declares a function called `Sum` with no parameters and returning `Island`.

Comment: Its a big project and i ask for help with only a small part of it. And its is compiling without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the problem is that you aren't setting the value of `area` field properly in the default constructor of `Island`. Just guessing though.

EDIT: The guess was right. In your default constructor you just define a local variable `area` and don't affect the instance's variable at all. The default constructor should look like this instead:

```
Island::Island() : area(1), islandName("Name") { }
```

Note the order of the members' initialisation -- in general it's a good practise to initialize the members in the same order that they were declared.